# Javascript regex and to get all the matches, it is similar to preg_match_all(PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-match-all

Is it possible in JavaScript to do something like preg_match_all does in PHP ?

I would like to be able to get two numbers from string:

```
var text = 'b463_z78';
```

into two separated variables:

```
var bannerID = 463;
var zoneID    = 78;
```

Comment: What is the format of the input string? One example doesn't cut it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
.match(/^b(\d+)_z(\d+)$/)
```

Assuming that the input string is strictly: start with `b`, digits, then underscore `_`, then `z`, then end with digits.

The 2 numbers are in index 1 and index 2 of the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

To match ALL numbers in a string you can use:

```
.match(/(?:\D*(\d+))*/);
```

So, if you had an input string of `'b463_z78'`, you'd get an array containing `'463'` and `'78'`, or if you had an input string of `'1a2b3c4d'` you'd get an array containing `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` and `'4'`.